# marquee text issue in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have textview in my xml like below

```
   <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:elevation="3dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_sound_name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/popins_reguler"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text='@{model.soundTitle}'
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

And below line in my java code:

```
binding.tvSoundName.setSelected(true);
```

I am using buildToolVersion 29.0.2

I have checked many questions and answers in stackoverflow and tried, I think I have all which should for make marquee working but still its not working, can anyone tell, whats wrong with this code, or any configuration I am missing.

Comment: Try to remove `LinearLayout`

Comment: I have tried to remove it and still not working!

Comment: What is not working text scrolling ? Is your text big enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this `binding.tvSoundName.isSelected = true` and my text is scrolling

Comment: binding.tvSoundName.setSelected(true)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width = "match_parent"
       android:gravity = "center_vertical"
       android:layout_height = "match_parent">
       <TextView
          android:id = "@+id/tv_sound_name"
          android:textSize = "20dp"
          android:textAlignment = "center"
          android:layout_width = "match_parent"
          android:ellipsize = "marquee"
          android:fadingEdge = "horizontal"
          android:marqueeRepeatLimit = "marquee_forever"
          android:scrollHorizontally = "true"
          android:textColor = "#ff4500"
          android:text = "Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
          android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
          android:singleLine = "true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and,

```
binding.tvSoundName.isSelected = true
```

Comment: Can you check using binding.tvSoundName.setSelected = true;